# problem with form elements when div is faded in from being display : none (IE problem)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

on a webpage I've been working on I have a problem which I seem unable to solve.

I have a div with display set to none which I fade in. it contains form-element which are not being shown the way they are supposed to when wieved in IE.

you can look at it at http://www.orrmyr.se

Thanks for you help
Martin

Answer (score 0):

have you tried having the form in another div inside the hidden one?

or us JS to hide the div onLoad instead of having hidden in CSS